# A concentric circle problem

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

we have drawn altitude $AH$ in triangle $ABC$ if bisection of the  $\angle HAB$ and $\angle HAC$ meet $BC$ at $D$ and $E$. Further, assume that $DE=AB+AC-BC$.
Prove the circumcenter of triangle $ADE$ and the center of the incircle of triangle $ABC$ are coincident.

my attempt:
I assumed segment bisectors of $AB$ and $AE$ meet each other at $O$ and I choose $T$ on $BC$ which  $\angle BOT$=90, therefore, we have to prove $\angle TOC$=$\angle DAC$ but I wasn't able to continue to a solution
actually, I don't know how to use $DE=AB+AC-BC$.

please share your ideas and solutions even if they're not complete.thanks!

you can also use this picture
[image]

Comment: Could you upload the drawing?

Comment: In the meantime i drew it myself, but just as in your picture, the centers don't look coincident to me? (non-native speaker, does coincident mean they have the same position?)

Comment: The problem is surprisingly difficult. So far I only managed to show that if the centers of the circles coincide, then $DE=AB+AC-BC$

Comment: Are there details like "mvdmnsf of AB and AE meet each other at O " missing out from above sketch by klirk? Is there a reference /source to this question?

Comment: @Narasimham so far I didn't scetch anything. What do you mean? I also don't know what mvdmnsf is supposed to mean?  I also would suggest this question to be reopened; this is probably no homework question. It could be competition material though

Comment: I posted an incomplete solution in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708817/solution-to-a-concentric-circle-problem

Comment: @klirk I agree with you that this is surprisingly difficult. I posted an imcomplete solution in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708817/solution-to-a-concentric-circle-problem . Maybe you can comment on it.

Comment: @Mick very nice, i like that the  question got attention again as I invested some time in coming up with an answer. I will look at the answers tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ugly solution using trigonometry.

Denote the length $AH$ by $1$, $\angle DAH, \angle EAH$ by $a, b$. Let $P$ be a point on $AB$ such that $PD\perp AB$. Then $AB=AP+PB=1+DH\tan{2a}=1+\tan{a}\tan{2a}$. Similarly $AC=1+\tan{b}\tan{2b}$. Hence the given equation is equivalent to:
$$\tan{a}+\tan{b}=\tan{a}\tan{2a}+\tan{2b}\tan{b}+2-\tan{a}-\tan{b}.$$
From $\tan{2a}=\frac {2\tan{a}}{1-\tan^2{a}}$ and write $x, y$ for $\tan{a}, \tan{b}$, this reduces to
$$(2+x+y)(xy+x+y-1)=0.$$
Because $x, y>0$, we have $xy+x+y-1=0$. Hence, $\tan{a+b}=\frac {x+y}{1-xy}=1$ i.e. $\angle BAC=2a+2b=\pi/2$.
Notice that now $\triangle ABE, \triangle ACD$ is isosceles with $AE, AD$ as bases. The angle bisectors of $\angle ABC, \angle ACB$ therefore bisect $AE, AD$ perpendicularly. The conclusion follows.

Comment: Fixed to $PD\perp AB$.

Comment: Your first big equation with all the tain it seems strange to me. Could you expand on that?

Comment: I meant $\tan$. To me it seems there should appear terms of the form $1/\cos$.  Or expressed differentely: If already $AB=1+\tan\alpha \tan 2\alpha$, then this equation would imply $BE=DE$ which is clearly wrong

Comment: thanks! it was a great solution and, beautiful...